# Parallel driving multiple pairs of LEDs in series from USB supply -- is it a terrible idea?

Tags: led, usb

Due to a need for a grow light and a surplus of 3mm LEDs & USB chargers on hand, I decided to try to make something serviceable with no additional parts requirements.

Upon measuring the LEDs, I found that the white ones I have have an average Vf of about 2.8. The reds have an average of about 2.0. Arranging them in series and running a couple tests off of my bench power supply just to see how hot they got/what output looked like, they appeared to be somewhat under-driven at 5V, drawing ~15mA. Ramping the supply up to 5.5V drove the test pair at about 50mA with no additional drift in current after several minutes.

Assuming that other pairs perform roughly the same, it seems to me that I could get away with running several pairs in parallel off of one of the many 5V USB charger wall adapters. I'm an utter novice, but from what I can see as long as the voltage regulation isn't utterly abysmal, the combined voltage drop of the LED pairs should self-limit the current they pass. Token research indicates that biggest flaws with many USB wall-warts is that they tend to experience voltage sags when approaching max output current -- which, in this case, would seem to be a positive if anything.

My question is: What am I missing, and why is this a horrible idea that will no doubt burn my apartment down the moment I look away and curse all of my relatives to an early grave? Is constructing a pair of rails and just bridging them with LED pairs until I bump into the maximum current output of the supply a viable solution?

Comment: It's like putting two 1 amp fuses in parallel hoping to produce a 2 amp fuse.

Comment: I don't think that's accurate. Two LEDs in parallel with a single current-limiting resistor behave like that - manufacturing differences mean one draws more current, heats up, draws more current still, and ultimately burns out leaving the other to handle all the current, which it can't and also fails.

In this case the limiting factor is the supply voltage. Failure of any parallel pair shouldn't cause a cascade, as I understand it, and individual LEDs shouldn't even fail unless the supply voltage is way out of spec.

Of course, that's as I understand it. If I'm wrong, please explain why.

Answer (score 2):

I would not design that way to just parallel the LED strings across the supply rails. As you already observed the current drawn by LEDs themselves increases exponentially with voltage supply change. Make sure to add an appropriate sized resistor in series with each LED string to limit the current to an amount that in compliance with the ratings of the LEDs.

Not directly inferred in your question but do not try to parallel the outputs of multiple USB chargers together.

Comment: The smallest value resistor I have on hand in sufficient quantity would be 220 ohms, which really under-drives even a single white LED. 3 in parallel would mean enough current to drive the LED at a good intensity. I've not got datasheets or the manufacturer for the LEDs to pull them, but from testing I know that intensity starts showing diminishing returns around 30mA and they don't instantly blow at 50mA.

So while subbing in a single resistor instead of the 2nd LED would be no additional work, the added effort of 2-3 in parallel seems like it isn't worth it if the supply regulates well.

Comment: @GV00 - I have to tell you that this is an "electrical engineering" Q&A site, Not necessarily a hack fest site. As such I stand by my answer. Just because you only seem to have 220 ohm resistors does not change the fundamental proper engineering response. 1) Resistors are cheap. 2) Resistors are available in a plethora of sizes (both ohms value and power rating value).

Comment: Very well, then consider it a theoretical question independent of the specifics, just so I can verify my thinking. If provided a voltage-limited supply from which a pair of LEDs in series are supplied within tolerance of Vf for the pair: A) Are there additional failure modes not dependent on the voltage moving out of spec, and B) Do further pairs in parallel introduce any complicating factors, as long as they're individually within spec?, and C) Not being an ideal power supply, would a common USB charger have complicating factors aside from voltage output tolerance?

Answer (score 0):

Besides from the fact that everything you build from scratch could burn your appartment down, I don‘t see a reason why this should not work.

Of course you need to do a proper power analysis of every involved component. And you need to check things at steady state temperature.